# Electric flux of a point charge in 2D

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I am working in two dimensions and have a point charge in the $x$-$y$ plane at the origin.  The charge is surrounded by a square walls, $-0.5<x<0.5$; $-0.5<y<0.5$, which are grounded. If I have to calculate the electric flux through the boundaries of the square, should I just calculate $\int \vec{E}\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{\ell} $ where $\mathrm{d}\vec{\ell}$ runs through the closed boundary? I ask this because until now, flux made sense to me, but only when talked about passing through some 2D region.

Comment: I have edited your post to add a little more clarity.  However, I'm not sure what you're getting at with your last sentence.  If you could try to revise that to really highlight the specific conceptual issue you're struggling with, I think this question could be on topic.

Comment: Yes. It is a slightly strange problem, since usually one works in 3D, but you can do the integral in a simplified manner which mimics the full 3D case.

Answer (score 1):

Flux in two dimensions into a curve $\mathcal{C}$ should be
$$
\Phi=\int_{\mathcal{C}} \vec{E}\cdot\hat{n}\, d\ell
$$
Where $\hat{n}$ is the unit normal vector to the curve.

This for instance is consistent with gauss's law $\Phi=\oint_{\mathcal{C}} \vec{E}\cdot\hat{n}\, d\ell=q_{in}/\epsilon$, when you notice that poisson equation in two dimensions for a point particle gives a potential $\varphi(r)\propto$ log $r$, which gives $E \propto 1/r$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a differential in your integrals, e.g., $\int_\mathcal{C}\mathbf E\cdot\hat n\,ds$?